# Loop php values from an echo in HTML

Tags: php, html, loops

I have a little issue when I try to to loop my php values in HTML. So far this is what I tried but I have not excpected result.

If I remove the loop I only get the first entry. I would like to echo all the possibles entries from my research.
This is my code ( from an SQL request).

```
<html>
               <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Surname</th>
                            <th>Number</th>
                            <th>Adress</th>
                            <th>link</th>

          <!--<th class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></th>-->
                   </tr>
                        <tr>
                <?php $rowG = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS);?>
                <?php foreach($array as $rowG=>$value): ?> <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $rowG[2]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rowG[1]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rowG[0]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rowG[3]?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "<a href='./consultation.php?Login=$rowG[2]'> Link </a>" ; ?></td>

            <?php endforeach;}} ?>

                       </tr>
                    </table>

</html>
```

Do you know where I made my mistake ?

Thank you for your help

Edit : Finally I managed to do it by using a `do{}while` loop.

Thank you all for your help

RFlow

Comment: `$array`? What is this?

Comment: `foreach($rowG as $array=>$value)`. First it goes the array name and then the current element name. Change those as well: `<?php echo $rowG[0,1,2,3...]; ?>` to `<?php echo $array[0,1,2,3...]; ?>`. Take a look at @u_mulder's answer. Much better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to guess what you are trying to do or even what actually happens, since I don't know what is assigned to `$rowG`, so I tried to hack meaning out of this from the code's errors and came up with that :

```
<?php
while ($rowG = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rowG[2]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rowG[1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rowG[0]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rowG[3]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo '<a href="./consultation.php?Login='.$rowG[2].'"> Link </a>'; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

If it doesn't work with you, you'll have to provide the informations that should have been included in your question since the begining.

Comment: What is assigned to $rowG ? The values that are in my DB and I get the results from my query. Do you also need the query ? For example $rowG[0] is an adress and $rowG[1] is a first name etc... Do you need more info ? I would like to echo the values from my query. Without loop it works but with a loop only the first entry is printed;

Comment: Why don't you use the string keys that your query returns instead of indexes ? Did you tried my code ?

Comment: Yes I tried it but nothing happen, No results printed. I had already tried this earlier in the day. thank you

Comment: @Rflow You know what to do, then.

Comment: I have used string keys but same result. I don't really know what to do.

Comment: I told you twice. Give all the significant information, which includes - but isn't limited to - the whole code involved, or try to handle it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is basic iteration over query results:

```
while ($rowG = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $rowG[2]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rowG[1]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rowG[0]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rowG[3]?></td>
    <td><?php echo "<a href='./consultation.php?Login=$rowG[2]'> Link </a>" ; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

Comment: `<td><?php echo "<a href='./consultation.php?Login={$rowG[2]}'> Link </a>" ; ?></td>`. I like to add curly braces around interpolated variables.

Comment: @Spectarion sometimes this definitely can help)

Comment: Yes. Especially if you need to add a prefix or suffix. Example: `{$logged_username}s profile` => `u_mulders profile`.

Comment: I know I tried it but I'm using <th> and it seems that is not working it print not well formated table.

Comment: `th` used in `thead` only. What do you mean by `not well formated`? You can edit your question and give more info, even pic of this table.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach($array as $rowG=>$value): ?> <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $rowG[2]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rowG[1]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rowG[0]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rowG[3]?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "<a href='./consultation.php?Login=$rowG[2]'> Link </a>" ; ?></td>

            <?php endforeach;}} ?>
```

Would be :

```
<?php foreach($rowG as $arr): ?> <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $arr[2]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $arr[1]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $arr[0]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $arr[3]?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "<a href='./consultation.php?Login=$arr[2]'> Link </a>" ; ?></td>

            <?php endforeach;}} ?>
```

Note the use of **$arr instead of $rowG**.
In the original code $array is not used.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but I have now 10 duplicate entries. Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: Try the query in mysql.  Review the code for an outer loop.